# create a dynamic element using javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a dynamic `<div>` element so I wrote this code to create a `<div>` to my knowledge. I can't find any mistake here so why does this code not work?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<title>scroll</title>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<script>
    function mydiv(){
        var elem=document.createElement("div");
        var t=elem.createAttribute("style");
        elem.createTextNode("ddfdfd");
        t.value="width:200px;height:1200px;border:1px solid black;";
        elem.setAttributeNode(t);
        document.body.appendChild(elem);
    }
    window.onload=mydiv();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Dev tools are your friend. `TypeError: Object #<HTMLDivElement> has no method 'createAttribute'`

Answer (score 2):

Most obvious mistake is that you assign window.onload to the return value of `mydiv()` instead of to the function itself. You should use `window.onload=mydiv;` instead (without parenthesis).

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
    <title>scroll</title>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
    <script>
       function mydiv(){
           var elem=document.createElement("div");   
           elem.innerText = "ddfdfd";
           elem.setAttribute('style', 'width:200px;height:1200px;border:1px solid black;');
           document.body.appendChild(elem);
       }
       window.onload=mydiv;
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: See my answer, you need to fix the window.onload bit.

Comment: thanks!but why my code isn't working?where the mistakes might be in my code?

Comment: i've foune if i use document.createAttribute instead of elem.createAttribute my codes works fine.why is that so? i mean,what is the difference between document.createAttribute and element.createAttribute?